# pytorch vectorizing over index subset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, vectorization

I'd like to vectorize an operation that involves subsetting into another tensor. I'm not sure if this can be done or if a for loop is necessary in this case. A simplified example, with the for loop is:

```
for i in range(1,result.shape[0]):
        result[i,:] = other_tensor[ list_of_subset_indices[i], :].prod(axis=0)
```

The "list_of_subset_indices" object is a list of lists of indices to subset the tensor. Is there any way to remove the loop over i?

Comment: I think it would be better if you provided a minimal example with inputs and desired output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does `torch.index_select(other_tensor, 0, list_of_subset_indices)` do what you want?

Comment: This doesn't work since `torch.index_select` needs `list_of_subset_indices` to be a tensor. In my case its a list of lists that are not all necessarily the same length. For example `list_of_subset_indices = [[1,2,3],[2,4],[1,5]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your operation is already vectorized, you can use a range to index your assignment:

```
r = range(1, len(result))
result[r] = other_tensor[list_of_subset_indices[r]].prod(0)
```

---

Two side questions:

- are you sure about the `1` in your range, it won't go over `index=0`?
- your output as duplicate data, are you sure it's a 2D tensor you want?

  In your code `other_tensor[ list_of_subset_indices[i], :].prod(axis=0)` is a single scalar that you are copying to all rows of `result`.

Comment: My `list_of_subset_indices` object is a list of lists and doesn't accept a range as input. For the side questions, (1) yes the first case (index=0) is different, (2) `other_tensor[ list_of_subset_indices[i], :].prod(axis=0)` ends up being a rank 1 tensor, not a scalar. The product is only over the first axis.